# How to link a username in Slack setTopic API

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am using the channels.setTopic API from slack to set the topic of my channel. The topic I'm setting contains a username. Unfortunately, after I make the API call, the topic text does not link the username correctly.

I've already tried to send link_names as true and as 1, but no success.

Help?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: @Duck yes, please look at the accepted answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparantly just putting the username inside <> does the trick, ex: <@username>

Comment: It did not work for me with the new conversations.setTopic function: https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.setTopic

Comment: This worked for me. I needed to use both the `<` `>` wrappers and also include an `@` sign ahead of the username.